# When do you get upgrades for the Promotional weapons?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Regarding the `promotional weapons`, as defined on the Mass Effect 3 [multi-player manifest page](http://social.bioware.com/1169915/&v=bw_games&game=masseffect3_pc&pid=400985083&display=multiplayer) online (Collector Rifle, N7 Valiant, N7 Crusader, N7 Eagle, N7 Hurricane), where do you get the level-ups for them?

The weapons themselves I believe only drop in the promo packs for winning weekend challenges (correct me if I'm wrong). But once you have any of those weapons, do the upgrades drop in regular packs, or do they also only drop in promo packs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weekly events are over and Commendation packs for completing those events no longer are attainable.

All weapons are now available through the packs in the store (purchasable by credits or bioware points).

[Patch Notes](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/343/index/9544143/2):

```
Commendation Pack Weapons
- The following weapons have been added to the ultra rare pool of cards
    - N7 Valkyrie Assault Rifle
    - N7 Eagle Pistol
    - N7 Crusader Shotgun
    - N7 Hurricane SMG
    - N7 Valiant Sniper Rifle
```

Collector Rifle is also in the store packs as a Rare.

Answer (score 3):

tiddy is incorrect about the "N7" weapons (they are very confusingly named, unfortunately): The promotional N7 weapons -- the Valiant, Hurricane, Eagle, and Crusader -- are distinct from the Ultra-Rares (despite the latter also having an N7 badge) and will not be granted by Spectre or Premium Spectre packs, even as upgrades. They also appear in a different section of the Multiplayer Manifest on your account on social.bioware.com.

You can **only** get upgrades to the N7 promotional weapons from Victory/Commendation packs, you cannot get them via any other method. For example, if you have level I of each of Valiant, Hurricane, Eagle, and Crusader, then the next Commendation Pack you receive will upgrade one of those weapons to II.

If you got really, really lucky with your VPs the highest level you could currently have of any of the N7 weapons (again, the Valiant, Hurricane, Eagle, and Crusader) would be VI, if you had received the same weapon every time (very unlikely).

Answer (score 3):

Well, as for the Collector Rifle, I'm not sure how, but I got it in a Premium Spectre pack without purchasing anything outside of the game itself.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, only the Collector's rifle is a pure promotional item.  You can only receive it by purchasing Razer gear, or other such promotions. It can only be upgraded by purchasing MORE hardware and getting more promo codes.  It can never be upgraded from random pack drops.

The N7 weapons you listed are considered "Ultra-Rares" and typically show up at a very low frequency in Spectre packs, and higher frequency in Premium Spectre packs.  Additionally, "Promotional Weekends" grant Victory and Commendation packs upon successful goal completion.  I believe Commendation packs are guaranteed to have at least 1 Ultra-Rare item or (N7).

To upgrade the N7 weapons from I-X you simply need to keep finding the weapon cards in your spectre and premium spectre packs, as well as the Commendation or possibly Victory packs.  It's random and can be very time consuming. Best of luck.

Comment: Well, when you look at the [online profile page, such as mine](http://social.bioware.com/1169915/&v=bw_games&game=masseffect3_pc&pid=400985083&display=multiplayer), it shows those weapons as "promotional". Which was the only reason I listed them as such.

Comment: The Prothean beam weapon is from the 'From Ashes' DLC - it is the item that Javik has on him when he is released from the stasis pod.

Comment: Forgot about that weapon. I don't actually see the Prothean rifle listed in the multi-player manifest page at all.